# How to mock a property set in the constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I created a HttpInterceptor and wrote a unit test for it.

Now I get this error message when I run the test:

> TypeError: Can not read property 'route' of undefined

This property is set in the constructor of my interceptor:

```
  constructor(
    service1: Service1,
    service2: Service1,
    ) {

    InterceptorService.service1 = service1;
    InterceptorService.service2 = service2;
    this.route = InterceptorService.service2.route.getValue(); // BehaviorSubject
  }
```

In my unit test, I call this constructor like this:

```
  const interceptorService = new InterceptorService(
    service1,
    service2
  );
```

How can I fix this error or mock the property so that it is no longer recognized as undefined.

Comment: Have you added the `HttpClientTestingModule` and  `HttpTestingController` inside your test component? Check this [info](https://alligator.io/angular/testing-http-interceptors/) for more details.

Comment: It is a little bit hard to answer your question from your code provided. But a general good idea is to set a breakpoint or debugger statement into the constructor before running the test. Then you can see what value service2 in the constructor has and how it got called. From that you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @jess Yes I have. My test has a similar structure as in your example. Before I set the route property, everything worked fine.

Comment: Question, why is it  `service2: Service1`? How about a `spyOn` on the service method?

Comment: would you mind providing more code as what `InterceptorService` is ? because you are using `InterceptorService.service1` . It would be better if u can provide more component code